# CommonJS vs ES Modules

Tags: javascript, commonjs, es6-modules

Could someone explains why CommonJS is dynamic, while ES is static? And what is dynamic and static mean in this context? And also I am quite confused about the difference between parse time and run time, hope someone could also explain that a little. Thanks!

Comment: "Static" refers to [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), for determining which dependencies a module has without executing the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's pedantic to say "parse time", as this refers to the time before running the app, normally called compile time. Modules allow some code to be examined and mapped in relation to each modules' file location, imports, and exports, before it is run - at "parse time".  Before a single function is run, each function is parsed, meaning its name and other properties are assembled such that other modules may import them. The result of function calls and the value of variables at this point is unknown but the function per se is known.

When importing using ES the variables, functions, etc that are imported are not *normally* dynamically assembled (there is a partly implemented proposal documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)), which happens at run time. Using ES the program explicitly states the dependencies regardless of any program variance. Importing in different order doesn't matter. Regardless of the soundness or lack thereof of the imported code the result is the same - i.e. static and the import statement is correct or incorrect before any of the code is evaluated to any value.

Because CommonJS evaluates more of the code at once than ES, more is known if followed in a sequential way. One of the implications is that code within the string of a require statement can have variables, making the statement dynamic, but ES cannot. ES exports are parsed but the entire module is not available to other modules that import it at the time the import statement is evaluated.

There is an [MDN article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive) that explains this more thoroughly.

Comment: "*Importing in different order doesn't matter.*" - that's not quite true. Initialisation order matters.

Comment: @Bergi, Are you saying initialization order of files matter or initialization order of imports within a file matter or both?

Comment: Both. The execution order of code matters, which implies that the order of import statements matters as well, since the former depends on the latter.

Comment: @Bergi Can you give an example where the order matter to an ES module import statement? I am aware that circular dependencies break normal ES module imports. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Circular dependencies are one thing, but in general if module code execution has side effects you might care about the order in which multiple modules are executed. In any case, it's not really different than commonjs (except for TDZ).